# Saved txt file weird and now cannot import to Excel

Tags: excel, python-3.x, text-files, notepad

My python code was to append one row at a time of multi-column data into a text file, which i then needed to pull apart column-by-column.. not row by row. It looks like a normal text document with elements split by spaces, meaning:

```
0.00000 107.07925 25.34190 -1.22487 0.63152
1.00000 88.51627 6.54154 -1.27440 0.90064
2.00000 76.58229 3.43457 -1.14756 0.88143
```

So on so forth. When i open the notepad file, that is what it looks like. But it copies-and-pastes weird...

```
0.00000
 107.07925
 25.34190
 -1.22487
 0.63152

1.00000
 88.51627
 6.54154
 -1.27440
 0.90064

2.00000
 76.58229
 3.43457
 -1.14756
 0.88143
```

And i have gone through all combinations of replacing all spaces with semicolons, ampersands, and even copy-and-pasting the amount of spaces a tab creates just in the effort of getting this to import into Excel..

Can anyone help me figure out what causes this issue and how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Open the file in a hex editor or viewer and figure out what's there that shouldn't be. We can't do that for you. :-)

Comment: Notepad doesn't follow \n line breaks - just \r\n - might be your issue.

Comment: @Gerrit0 I believe that may have contributed, because i was using \n... Now i am running into a separate issue, i'll try this as soon as i stop getting [Errno 13] "Permission denied" errors...

Comment: Maybe you have the file opened exclusively by another application, or maybe your macro doesn't properly close the file after reading its content.

Answer (score 0):

As for opening it in Excel since it is split by spaces you might try changing the text to columns option setting to be space instead of the default tab. This option is listed under the data tab(Excel 2013). As far as I know the easiest way to do this would be to open a blank excel sheet type anything into A1 and then click the text to columns button. Select delimited and then Next change the options on this page to space instead of tab then finish. Now delete whatever you typed into Excel. You can copy and paste the data into this excel window now and it should work for you. Now this setting will reset when you close and reopen excel.